# json_decode only return first member of a set

Tags: php, json

I have some JSON strings stored in an associative array. I can access these strings fine, but *json_decode* is only pulling out the last member of each set and omitting the last set entirely. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

This code

```
foreach ($arr_data as $row) {
    echo $row['tags'];
    print_r (json_decode($row['tags'], TRUE));      
}
```

outputs this

```
{"bun_tag": "punctuation"},{"bun_tag": "quotation marks"},{"bun_tag": "document heading"},{"bun_tag": "document structure"}{"bun_tag": "multiple inversion"},{"bun_tag": "overloaded compound"},{"bun_tag": "syntactic ambiguity"},{"bun_tag": "excessive syntactic distance"}{"bun_tag": "omission"},{"bun_tag": "referential distortion"}{"bun_tag": "tense"},{"bun_tag": "modality"},{"bun_tag": "nominalisation"},{"bun_tag": "directive infinitive"}{"bun_tag": "good"}

Array
(
    [bun_tag] => good
)

{"bun_tag": "garden path"},{"bun_tag": "overloaded compound"}{"bun_tag": "missing determiner"},{"bun_tag": "referential ambiguity"}{"bun_tag": "garden path"}

Array
(
    [bun_tag] => garden path
)

{"bun_tag": "overloaded compound"}

Array
(
    [bun_tag] => overloaded compound
)

{"bun_tag": "capitalisation"},{"bun_tag": "title of document section"}{"bun_tag": "syntactic ambiguity"},{"bun_tag": "excessive syntactic distance"}{"bun_tag": "selectional restriction"}

Array
(
    [bun_tag] => selectional restriction
)

{"bun_tag": "garden path"},{"bun_tag": "overloaded compound"},{"bun_tag": "syntactic ambiguity"}{"bun_tag": "relational ambiguity"},{"bun_tag": "containment relationship"}{"bun_tag": "punctuation"},{"bun_tag": "weak interruption"}{"bun_tag": "meaning unclear"},{"bun_tag": "domain terminology"}{"bun_tag": "homonymy"},{"bun_tag": "nominalisation"},{"bun_tag": "meaning unclear"},{"bun_tag": "domain terminology"},{"bun_tag": "referential ambiguity"}{"bun_tag": "document structure"}

Array
(
    [bun_tag] => document structure
)

{"bun_tag": "polysemy"},{"bun_tag": "agent / receiver"},{"bun_tag": "relational distortion"}
```

Comment: You keep using the same key, of course it will only return the last one. I'd guess the last one is invalid some other way. `var_dump()` instead of `print_r()` will probably show you it returns false.

Comment: The data in `$row['tags']` is not valid JSON.

Comment: Perhaps what you want to do is have your JSON look like `{"bun_tag": ["punctuation", "quotation marks", "document heading", ...]}`

Comment: Use `var_dump()` instead of `echo` or `print_r()` and re-post your output, because from what little useful information we can glean from your current post it looks more like this code should not return anything but errors.

Comment: Thank you, Siguza. You were right.

Answer (score 0):

As per Siguza's comment, the JSON string wasn't well formed. Solved by adding square brackets at either end, like so

```
foreach ($arr_data as $row) {
    echo $row['tags'];
    print_r (json_decode('[' . $row['tags'] . ']', TRUE));      
}
```

This converts the input string to a valid array.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What you're doing is decoding json string to become an associative array with duplicated keys, so it's gonna return one result each.

Comment: That works okay for my use case. I need to loop through the results anyway, and the data set is very small, so one more nominal layer does not incur much of a penalty on performance.